# What PHP default_timezone_set based on?

Tags: datetime, date

I want to use the same time on master and slave.
I did that and has problem about date not return the same:

**Server #1:**

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
date('r'); // => Thu, 17 Nov 2011 09:16:11 -0800
```

**Server #2:**

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
date('r'); // => Thu, 17 Nov 2011 08:40:21 -0800
```

**Server #3:**

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
date('r'); // => Thu, 17 Nov 2011 02:24:30 -0800
```

Any reason date('r') not return the same value on all server with same timezone set?

Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

maybe the time is simple set wrong on the system. you could try to use a timeserver to fetch the date if you dont have enough rights.